# Separate a row into many using separated by

Tags: r

Having into one row of dataframe data like this:

```
data.frame(text = c("in this line ???? another line and ???? one more", "more lines ???? another row")
```

separate into many rows using as separation the ????. Here the expected output

```
data.frame(text = c("in this line", "another line and", "one more", "more lines", "another row")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- data.frame(text = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$text),split = " \\?{4} ")))
```

or a more efficient (Thanks to comments by @Sotos)

```
dfout <- data.frame(text = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$text),split = " ???? ", fixed = TRUE)))
```

such that

```
> dfout
              text
1     in this line
2 another line and
3         one more
4       more lines
5      another row
```

Comment: If you do `sep = ' ???? '` and add `fixed = TRUE`, it will dramatically increase the efficiency by bypassing the regex engine

Comment: @Sotos thanks for the information, good to learn that